# Why does removing 'const' from the constructor parameter stop the class from being instantiated?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17

Removing `const` from line 12 prevents the class `What` from being instantiated during compilation. I do not expect `What` to ever be instantiated, regardless of constness in the declaration. This is consistent between clang, gcc and MSVC so I assume it is standard. Marking the constructor `explicit` also does not prevent the instantiation. What am I not understanding here? Why does constness make a difference?

```cpp
template <typename T> constexpr bool just_false() { return false; }

template<typename T>
class What {
    static_assert(just_false<T>(), "Why was this class instantiated?");
};

struct The {};

struct Heck {
    Heck(The) {}
    Heck(const What<int>&); // Removing 'const' from this line stops 'What<int>' from being instantiated
};

int main() {
    The the;
    Heck{the};
}
```

The `just_false` incantation is just to prevent the static assert from always triggering regardless of instantiation.

Compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/8cETcfss5

Comment: Note [\[temp.inst\]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#9) says "If the function selected by overload resolution can be determined without instantiating a class template definition, it is unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place." So it's nice of the compilers to skip the instantiation when the `const` is absent, but even in that case they're not required to, and the program could still fail to compile.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If `const` is there, and `What<int>` happens to have a constructor taking `The`, that would allow `Heck(const What<int> &)` to be used (because a const reference can bind to a temporary produced by such constructor). Checking for that constructor of `What<int>` requires instantiating the `What<int>` template.

If there is no `const`, no implementation of `What<int>` could possibly make `Heck(What<int> &);` be called, so there's no point in instantiating it.

---

But it seems that no matter what constructor `What<int>` has, the `Heck(The)` overload would take precedence, so strictly speaking, this instantiation seems to be unnecessary in this specific case.

Comment: @DaveMagnets A non-const lvalue reference can't bind to a temporary. A constructor of `What<int>` we're looking for would produce a temporary, which we couldn't bind to the reference.

Comment: I was confused by your answer until I realized that when you said "instantiating `What<int>`", you meant instantiating the template, not instantiating the class.  -- Obvious in retrospect, but confusing on first read.

Comment: @R.M. "Instantiating" always refers to templates. For an object, you'd say "create an instance of ...", or "create an object/variable of type ...".

Comment: I apologize if I'm not 100% up to speed on the minutiae of "official" C++ terminology. I was simply pointing out that (even if it's technically "incorrect" for C++, if not necessarily other languages), "instantiate" is commonly used by many people to mean "create an instance of a class", so you could make your answer clearer to more readers by editing it. Perhaps by changing it to "_Checking for that constructor of What<int> requires instantiating the What<int> template." or similar. A minor edit can greatly help clarity.

Answer (score 8):

If `What` had a constructor such as `What::What(The)`, then the implicit conversion `Heck(What(the))` would be valid for `Heck::Heck(const What&)` but not for `Heck::Heck(What&)`.

During overload resolution for the call `Heck(the)`, the search for viable functions eliminates `Heck::Heck(What&)` but does not eliminate `Heck::Heck(const What&)`, which gets carried over to the search for a best viable function, which requires instantiating `What`.

Comment: It can't be called with an rvalue. cppreference says "For every argument there must be at least one implicit conversion sequence that converts it to the corresponding parameter"

Answer (score -2):

Will this stop the error message?

```
struct Heck {
    Heck(The const&) {}; // Removing 'const' from this line causes 'What<int>' to be instantiated
    Heck(const What<int>&);
};
```

This is supposed to prevent implicit conversion/copy constructor call.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps this should be a separate question or a comment?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, SB did. I should ask the rationale behind it.

Comment: SB? What do you mean?